# Post a photo on facebook user's timeline from JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api

this is my goal:
implement a facebook share of an IMG on user's timeline, I have a facebook app already up and running and I have a standalone js-html5 app that generate the IMG.
I would like to post on user's timeline this IMG. 
This img has no url because the app is a standalone app, so doesn't write on server the img. I'm wondering how to make it from JS or from PHP.
Any Ideas how to implement?
Thanks everyone who will help me :)

Comment: You first need to get your FB app verified by the authorisation process on facebook, to allow for the `publish_actions` and `upload` permissions to be set.  then you can use the API to upload photo's to the profile.

Comment: Thanks RaggaMuffin-420 for your insight...I hope the authorisation process on facebook isn't too complex! Regards the rest have you got some tutorial or resources to point me trough? Thanks

Comment: well facebook developers reference is always a good place to look: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Comment: OK...I will have a look! Btw a quick question...do you know if is possible or better upload a js variable containing and IMG or an encoded jpg with FB api?